# Metric on the reals defined as a piecewise function involving absolute values.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

1. In the metric space $ (\mathbb R, |. |) $, We define
   $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
   |x-y| & \text{ if } x,y\in\mathbb Q\ \text{or}\ x,y\in\mathbb Q^c \\ 
   |x|+|y| & \text{another case}
   \end{cases}$$

Prove that $ d $ is a metric in $ \mathbb R $.

2. Let $B = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x ^ 2 \geq y \}$. Prove that $ B $ is convex.

**My attempt**
It is enough to prove that $ d (x, y) $ fulfills the triangular inequality, since the other two properties for it to be a metric space, are clearly fulfilled.

We must prove the triangle inequality in the case of x, y, z
taken from different subsets. Because if they are in the same subset, it is also clearly true.

If $x, y ∈ \mathbb Q$, $z ∈ \mathbb Q^c$
we have $d (x, y) = | x - y |$, while
$d (x, z) = | x | + | z |, d (y, z) = | y | + | z |$.
Obviously $| x - y | ≤ | x| + | z | + |y| + | z |$.
Now we consider the case $x ∈ \mathbb Q$, $y \in\mathbb Q^c$
, $z \in\mathbb Q$. The inequality
$d (x, y) = | x | + | y | ≤ | x - z | + | y | + | z | = d (x, z) + d (z, y)$
yes, it is valid.

If we assume that $z \in\mathbb Q^c$.
, the left side of the inequality does not
changes, while the right side increases in value.
The other cases correspond to the same estimates.

Therefore $ d $ is a metric in $ \mathbb R $.

With 2, I don't know how to prove that $ B $ is convex. Some help for this subsection.

Comment: You should spend a few seconds coming up with a less generic subject title.

Comment: Sorry, in the titles I am direct with the issues. I'm not so creative about it hahaha :).

Comment: Ah good, I'll change it :).

Comment: I was about to change the title to "Metric on the reals defined as a piecewise function involving absolute values", but you beat me to it. If you like mine better, feel free to use it. I didn't mention the convex set question, however. BTW, I was originally thinking of something like "Strange metric on the reals", but decided to be less flashy and more informative.

Comment: Thanks, for that suggest :).

Comment: Take $(2,-1), (-3,8) \in B$, then $0.5(2,-1)+0.5(-3,8)=(-0.5,3.5) \notin B$. $d$ is a metric and your approach is right.